# Launch an app from notification

Tags: android, ios, notifications, mobile-application

I am building an application using PhoneGap, which revolves around a timer I have created. I am struggling at the moment as I need a way of having the app open itself if the timer reaches zero. I have currently put in place a notification for when the timer runs out, and the user can launch the app from there. However I need a way of launching the app if the user "misses" the notification or something similar.

For example, when the timer on the local "timer" app on a mobile device runs out, it will open itself to notify the user that the time has ran out.

Any suggestion would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the code for opening the launcher Activity instead of showing notification in your service class.When the timer runs out the launcher activity will start instead of notification.
the code will look similar to this:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //calling Launcher Activity
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmScreen.class);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        alarmIntent.putExtras(intent);

        getApplication().startActivity(LauncherActivity.class);

        AlarmManagerHelper.setAlarms(this);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

I hope you are satisfied with this answer.